# Publish SharePoint Provider Hosted app to office store

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

Can I publish SharePoint Provider Hosted app to office store?

I can't publish autohosted app to office store

Comment: I have put together a small tutorial in a video on SP24 conference site, to publish provider-hosted apps in detail. Let me know if you have questions:

SP24 conference site: https://www.sp24conf.com/2014-1/Conf/SP24S028/ConfPages/SessionRoom.aspx

Comment: That link does not work..

Answer (score 1):

The infrastructure for autohosted apps will remain in preview status for a period of time after SharePoint 2013 releases. Autohosted apps will not be accepted by the Office Store during this preview phase.

Source: [APP Validation Policy FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj591603%28v=office.15%29.aspx) 
[APP Validation Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220035%28v=office.15%29.aspx)